# Show syntax error near "set" in database

Tags: android, database, sqlite, android-sqlite

The following line showed me the error as sytax error near "SET"

```
         db.update( TABLE_SECOND_NAME,cv, " SET " + COL_SECOND_2 + "= ( CONCAT 
              "+ (COL_SECOND_3+ ", " +name)+ "'ROLL=?",new String[]{roll});
```

I want to keep the both values old and new one during updating.The first value which is store already and the new one which is now updating.
the log as:

```
       09-29 14:20:37.021 27122-27122/com.example.prince.studentrecord
       E/ViewRootImpl: sendUserActionEvent() mView == null     
      09-29 14:20:37.581 27122-27122/com.example.prince.studentrecord 
       ViewPostImeInputStage ACTION_DOWN  
      09-29 14:20:38.941 27122-27122/com.example.prince.studentrecord 
          D/ViewRootImpl: 
      09-29 14:20:39.231 27122-27122/com.example.prince.studentrecord 
       E/ViewRootImpl: sendUserActionEvent() mView == null
      09-29 14:20:42.061 27122-27122/com.example.prince.studentrecord   

   09-29 14:20:42.161 27122-27122/com.example.prince.studentrecord   
      E/SQLiteLog: (1) near "SET": syntax error
```

Comment: int update (String table, 
                ContentValues values, 
                **String whereClause,**
                String[] whereArgs) ... basic sql question: can we use "SET" in where?

Comment: ...and no,  you cannot use `SQLiteDatabase.update` to update column with value from other column

Comment: What you did was mixing the `execSQL()` syntax (normal SQL command) with the `update()` method, which overrides the normal SQL UPDATE command.

Answer (score 0):

Use These method for update table of sqlite datebase :

public int updateContact(Contact contact) {
        SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();

```
    ContentValues values = new ContentValues();  
    values.put(KEY_NAME, contact.getName());  
    values.put(KEY_PH_NO, contact.getPhoneNumber());  

    // updating row  
    return db.update(TABLE_CONTACTS, values, KEY_ID + " = ?",  
            new String[] { String.valueOf(contact.getID()) });  
}
```

Comment: I wrote all thing right as:  public boolean updateData_Second(String roll,String name,String father,String cont,String cls,String datbirth)
    {
        SQLiteDatabase db=this.getWritableDatabase();
        ContentValues cv=new ContentValues();
        cv.put(COL_SECOND_1,roll);
        cv.put(COL_SECOND_2,name);
        cv.put(COL_SECOND_3,father);
        cv.put(COL_SECOND_4,cont);
        cv.put(COL_SECOND_5,cls);
        cv.put(COL_SECOND_6,datbirth);
       db.update(TABLE_SECOND_NAME,cv, "ROLL= ?",new String[]{roll});return true;

Comment: Remove " befor ROLL and put + after ROLL and then put "

Comment: db.update(TABLE_SECOND_NAME,cv, ROLL+"= ?",new String[]{roll}) like these @siraliza

Comment: To update the record it work...but I want to keep the old value befor the updation and the new one after the updation using concat function.....see the question carfully

Comment: Than you have to add in database not update the database.

Comment: actually i want to store the student daily attendence.If a studnt is present at day1,it store "present" so in this case if that student is absen at another day so then it replace the "present' with "absent" so then how to find the whole attendence after month

Comment: For that you have to create database with two column present and absent and when student is present increase the value of present column by 1 and same for the absent

Comment: can you please explain with example

Comment: Sorry. I can't.

Comment: I know but i have to no time for that it will take time.. so sorry.. i will only give you idea for your problem. sorry once again

Comment: I completed all the coding for student registration,deletion,updation,password confirmation,photo addition and retrieving with proper record,but at the last i stuck for 2 days in this one point as student attendence daily basis..